# Query for updating category for specific wordpress posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

I have a Wordpress website & currently I have more than 250 blogs. I also have assigned some categories to each blog posts. Right now, I have 110 categories and I need to reduce 110 categories to 11 new categories.

So for that first I'm removing all categories from all posts. Then I will add 11 new categories. I need to assign single category for the posts I choose.

> Eg: Category A for posts with post_id : 1, 15, 230, 84

What I need is an SQL Query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The below update query should work

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET category = 'category name' 
WHERE post_id in (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the table which connects both category and posts?

Comment: Getting this error: mysql> UPDATE b15_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = 5200 WHERE object_id in (106298,220769);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '106298-5200' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Are the data spread in single table or two different tables? 
can you share the table description, please?